# Defining variable in functions.php and using it as an "if statement" in other pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a couple of variables defined in my single.php and below it, I have an if statement calling the variables. My question is, how can I define the variables in functions.php and use them in single.php.

Simply adding a variable to functions.php and calling them in single.php does not work.

Right now, I have this in my single.php -

```
<?php 
    $prevPost = get_previous_post();
    $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, 'keepreading-thumb');

    if ( $prevPost ) : ?>
      <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail"); ?>
      <h3><?php previous_post_link('%link'); ?></h3>
      <p><?php echo excerpt(25); ?></p>
    <?php endif;
?>
```

I would like to add `$prevPost` and `$prevthumbnail` to the functions.php and have only the if statements in single.php.

Comment: When did you include the file `function.php`?

Comment: @Gwenc37 The theme `function.php` in Wordpress is included before any content file gets included.

Comment: I've often seen the keyword `global` in Wordpress themes. That should do the trick. **Update:** Here is an even [better solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38156/how-to-access-variables-from-functions-file-in-theme-files).

Answer (score 0):

**Add in your functions.php**

```
apply_filter("prevPost", "get_prevPost");
function get_prevPost($arg=""){
    return $values_of_prevPost; // you can use function call here or litteral 
}
```

**When you need to use prevPost, use it like below.**

```
apply_filters( 'prevPost', '' );
```

Same will go for other variables.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what goes where. I am very new to coding and would appreciate it if you could tell me. So, if you could spend a couple of minutes and give me a code that I can simply copy and paste to my functions.php and single.php. I am trying to get a code similar to the one on my question. Thank you :)